# How can I find mean value of time such that '0:00:34.805936', '0:01:17.946625' , '0:01:41.294841' (hour : minute:seconds) where they given in string

Tags: python, time, mean

Mean value of the time

I tried df[].mean() method, but it is not working. There should be another changing to use it, I can't find it

Comment: How are you planning to get a mean of a string? You need to convert the column to datetime first.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `strptime` to parse them into a `datetime` object, then construct a `timedelta` using the value parsed by `datetime`.

AFter that, sum the values up and divide by the length to get the mean.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def stringToTimeDelta(str):
    dt = datetime.strptime(str, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return timedelta(hours=dt.hour, minutes=dt.minute, seconds=dt.second, microseconds=dt.microsecond)

input = ["0:00:34.805936", "0:01:17.946625", "0:01:41.294841"]

# Convert string to timedelta
parsed = [stringToTimeDelta(x) for x in input]

# Maths operation on timedelta
print(sum(parsed, timedelta(0)) / len(parsed))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to a [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) first:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'elapsed': ['0:00:34.805936', '0:01:17.946625', '0:01:41.294841']})
df.elapsed = pd.to_timedelta(df.elapsed)
print(df.elapsed.mean())
```

Output:

```
0 days 00:01:11.349134
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution could be to use the .split() function.

```
time = "0:01:17.946625"
some_list = time.split(":")
```

This splits the string whenever it sees ":". The list is now:
["0", "01", "17.946625"]
Then, use a list comprehension to convert them to integers.

```
int_list = [int(item) for item in some_list]
```

Now, the list is
[0, 1, 17.946625]
Then, you can convert this list into seconds.

```
hours_to_seconds = int_list[0] * 3600
mins_to_seconds = int_list[1] * 60
seconds = hours_to_seconds + mins_to_seconds + int_list[2]
```

Now, you have seconds. You can calculate the mean by storing all the seconds in a list.

```
time_list = [val1, val2, val3]  # this list should have the seconds that you calculated
average = sum(time_list) / len(time_list)
```

Now, you have the average time. Please keep in mind that this is an extremely  easy and inefficient way to get the average time, and other answers will definitely be more complex.